# Pass argument to controller on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So, i started learning MVC, and i need to pass an email to a controller. (Trying to make a standard email signup)

Therefore i have an input and a button which (should) pass the input to an argument accepting controller and then redirect to another view.

I have the following controllers:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string mail)
{
    person = new EmailSignup{Email = mail};
    return RedirectToAction("details");
}

public ActionResult details()
{
    return View(person);
}
```

This is what i have in my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <form class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label class="margin20">Sign up for newsletter</label>
            <input type="Email" class="form-control" style="display:inline-block; max-width:200px" id="mail" placeholder="Example@Example.com" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="display:inline-block" id="emailSignup">Signup</button>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

It redirects to my "details" view, but my email is not showing.

Furthermore, is this best practice? would i want to do it like this?

Comment: Generate your html correctly using the strongly types `HtmlHelper` methods - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)` - your manul input does not even have a `name` attribute so its value will never be submitted. And you method should be `public ActionResult Index(EmailSignup model)` - bind to your model

Comment: but if i use my `HtmlHelper` it tells me "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation". No idea what that means.

Comment: The first line in your view needs to be `@model yourAssembly.EmailSignup` (and its recommend you pass an instance of the model to the view in the GET method - e.g. `return View(new EmailSignup());`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I just cant seem to understand why it is recommended that i pass an instance of the model to the view? 
By the way, i have my constructor outside my action methods, is that a good thing?

Comment: It just ensures that the model in the view is not `null`, and code that references a property of the model (e.g. `<div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>`) wont throw exceptions. And code for initializing the model should ideally be in the method but can be outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` renders a form, you don't need a second one inside it (if you need to add the `class`, you can use an overload of `Html.BeginForm`). Your input contains an `id` property, but not a `name` property. `name` is what's used when an action happens inside a form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer


<input type="Email" class="form-control" style="display:inline-block; max-width:200px" name="mail" id="test" placeholder="Example@Example.com" />

i changed to this, and deleted my form tags, still not posting to controller.